# Custom UITableviewcell not focusing for voice over left-right swipe

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

Voice over left-right swipe is not working after a particular cell when the next cell is either not visible in screen or partially visible in screen in UITableView.it gets stuck on the last label of the current cell and gives the boink sound if I try to left-right swipe. But if I manually scroll the screen the tableview cell becomes focusable

I want the voiceover focus to move to next element when doing left-right swipe. Not able to figure out what is causing the issue or find any work around also.